# React Native Overlay on a ScrollView

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, jsx, overlay

Here's my code atm.:

'''

```
return(
    < SafeAreaView style = {style.main}>
        
        


        
        <ScrollView style= {{backgroundColor: ""}}>
            
                <View style = {style.container}>
                    
                        <Food style = {style.food} image = {require("../../assets/icon.png")} />
                        <Food style = {style.food} image = {require("../../assets/icon.png")} />
                        <Food style = {style.food} image = {require("../../assets/icon.png")} name = "Sajtos  Csiga" price = "5000 Ft"/>
                        <Food style = {style.food} image = {require("../../assets/icon.png")} />
                        <Food style = {style.food} image = {require("../../assets/icon.png")} />
                        <Food style = {style.food} image = {require("../../assets/icon.png")} />
                        <Food style = {style.food} image = {require("../../assets/icon.png")} />
                        <Food style = {style.food} image = {require("../../assets/icon.png")} />
                    
                    
                        
                </View>
        </ScrollView>
        <Overlay style = {style.overlay}/>
        
        

        


    </SafeAreaView >
)'''
```

And the the thing what I'd like to achieve would look like this:

[image: goal]

Where the Overlay would be the "BUFEE".

Can you help me with the CSS (or more like the StyleSheet), please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<SafeAreaView >
    <ScrollView>
     // Do your stuff
    </ScrollView>

    <View style={style.overlay}>
    </View>              
</SafeAreaView >
```

After that, you can use something like this for the style of overlay:

```
overlay:{
        width: your preference,
        height: your preference,
        position:'absolute',
        bottom: 20,
    }
```

Comment: Thank you soo much, it solved it. I should stop wasting hours while being tired trying to solve CSS.

Comment: Glad to hear, you can upvote and accept my answer if you found it useful @AdriaNn01